# How to get a class to inherit from all of the same classes that another class does

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

When you create a class, one of the inputs is a tuple of base classes to inherit from.

For example,

```
class K(str, list, dict):
    pass
```

...or...

```
Klass = type("Klass", (Class1, Class2, Class3), dict())
```

I want a class to inherit from all of the same classes that another class does. `inspect.getmro()` returns something far more complicated than a simple tuple where each element is a class.

Suppose that we wanted the same method resolution order.

```
def mro2tuple(_mro):
    # MAGIC HAPPENS HERE
    return tuppy
```

How do we get a tuple of base classes from the method resolution order? I was wondering if I could write something like the following:

```
import inspect
Klass1_mro = inspect.getmro(Klass1)
bases = mro2tuple(Klass1_mro):
Klass2 = type("Klass2", bases, dict())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't try to inherit from the mro, just inheriting from the bases of the other class should be enough.

```
new_class = type('Newclass', old_class.__bases__, {})
```